# Obtaining logging history in Python

Tags: python, logging

I'm using the logging module in Python 2.7.  I have a logger with different children and two handlers.

How can I check if the logger handled an event of a certain level (eg. an exception)?

Comment: Do you mean "ensure that" rather than "check if"? You normally check if something happened by looking at the logs :-)

Comment: I want to send a mail (with the log file in attachment) if any of the messages has a level above a certain value. I could indeed search the log-file, but that's rather a dirty workaround imho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be to write a custom handler which took the appropriate action specific to your needs. For example, you could use a [`MemoryHandler`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#memoryhandler) subclass with a flush level set to the level value you want, and the `flush()` method could be overridden to send an email (ideally, in a separate thread, if responsiveness is important).